# Recovering MySQL root password (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql

I posted this on StackOverflow and was told to come here.

I have an XAMPP MySQL installation and want to recover the root password. I am aware that questions have asked this already, however they are Linux methods of doing it (I'm on Windows) and I can't seem to figure out what exactly the Linux commands translate to in XAMPP - I tried looking for a place to configure the arguments to not use network etc but couldn't. This is a localhost installation.

Comment: Does this work? https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=151

Comment: @James it did, thanks a load! It was a little outdated in that it said line 18 but the file now actually has only 15 lines (it was on line 8) but the end result was the same.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I think you could document the steps that worked for you and then self-answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I can now answer this question myself, thanks to the help of @James in the comments. The article [here](https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=151) was helpful, but not 100% accurate anymore, so here is how to do it for anyone in the future:

1. Navigate to the mysql folder (**C:/xampp/mysql** in my case).
2. Open **resetroot.bat** in a text editor.
3. Look for line 8 (the article above specifies line 18 - the file is only 15 lines long now)
4. Add `–datadir=c:/xampp/mysql/data` into the `mysql\bin\mysqld.exe` line after `–no-defaults`
5. Run **resetroot.bat** and you're done :)

Answer (score 5):

This **resetroot.bat** method did not work for me, even after following the instructions above.

My XAMPP uses this DB version:

- **Server:** MariaDB
- **Server version:** 10.0.17-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

However, using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4124506/321716), I was able to do it manually.

- Go to your **xampp\mysql\bin** folder
- Edit **my.ini** and insert `skip-grant-tables` below `[mysqld]`
- Restart MySQL
- Set new password for your **root** user by running `UPDATE mysql.user SET
  Password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root'` in phpMyAdmin in
  the mysql database (or just leave it like this if MySQL cannot be
  accessed from remote hosts)
- Remove the `skip-grant-tables` in the **my.ini** file

Comment: note - [won't work in 10.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540)