# Problem accessing MySQL in Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed Xampp on my Ubuntu 22.04 box.

In its `my.cnf`, I set

```
[client]
password =mypassword
port     =3306
socket   =/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I saved this and restarted MySQL.

When I try Ubuntu's mysql client:

```
$ mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 -u root -p -S /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

it asked for a password where I gave the configured password but it said

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What do I need to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering MySQL root password (XAMPP)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/recovering-mysql-root-password-xampp)

Comment: @danblack see my answer, that helped, yes.

Answer (score 0):

@danblack, your quoted question [Recovering MySQL root password (XAMPP)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/recovering-mysql-root-password-xampp) included an sql system command

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root'
```

which I invoked in PhPMyAdmin. I had to restart the MySQL server and then

```
$ mysql  -u root -p
```

worked.

Comment: I actually mean the other answer. This one is really dumb as it modifies the internal data structures rather than using `SET PASSWORD` and other SQL that directly modifies users. It also will not work on MariaDB-10.4+ which is what XAMPP is (its not MySQL, and its sad they mislead their users about what's included).

Answer (score -1):

Specifying `-p` on the command line will make it ask for a password.

Try omitting it

```
$ mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 -u root -S /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```